# Disc brake pads - steel vs aluminium back plate

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, brake-pads

I am looking at a set of Organic Disc brake pads. The brake pads come with a steel back plate or as an aluminium back plate. Why would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some Tektro calipers use a magnet to retain and position the brake pad. The magnet is part of the caliper piston so the pad backing material would have to be steel.Most hydraulic brake pistons are aluminum to reduce weight and resist corrosion.If your pistons are aluminum I would use the aluminum pads due to the possible corrosion caused by the disimilar metals (steelpad against an aluminum piston).

Comment: excellent, answered all my concerns

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum has better heat transfer properties than steel, the pads should run cooler. Shimano's XT rotors are aluminum sandwiched between two stainless layers and Shimano claims they run cooler by as much as 100 degrees Celsius.